# Abbreviated Notation for Groups, Rings and Fields

Tags: mathematics, notation, abstract-algebra

Groups, Rings and Fields are often referred to by the set involved without mention of the operation(s). For example, the "group (G,+)" may be called the "group G".

When did this practice originate and why?

It seems the labour saved in writing "G" instead of "(G,+)" (for example) is trivial compared with the loss of clarity and precision so I wonder what other reasons there could be?

Comment: One might first ask whether $G$ or $(G,+)$ came first.  (I don't know, but I suspect the **notation** $(G,+)$ came later.)

Comment: About "loss of clarity"... have you actually spent much time working with groups, rings, or fields? There is essentially never a problem caused by referring to a group, ring, or field by the name of the underlying set. In the rare situations when an actual confusion might arise (e.g., regarding the real numbers as a topological group with the discrete topology instead of its usual topology) a special one-time notation is used (e.g., $\mathbf R_d$ for that topological group).  You are asking about a problem that is never a problem to those who work with groups, rings, and fields.

Answer (score 3):

The shift seems quite recent.

For the "short" writing, see some "old" Algebra's textbook, like:

- Bartel van der Waerden, [Modern Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderne_Algebra), Vol.I (1949 - or.ed.1930-31): page 11 for *groups* and page 38 for *rings*;
- Nicolas Bourbaki, [Elements of Mathematics. Algebra I: Chapters 1-3](https://books.google.it/books?id=STS9aZ6F204C&printsec=frontcover) (1998 - or.ed.1970), page 30:

> **Definition 1**. A set with an associative law of composition, possessing an identity element and under which every element is invertible, is called a group. 
>   [...] If $G$ and $H$ are two groups, ...

- Garrett Birkhoff & Saunders Mac Lane, [A Survey of Modern Algebra](https://books.google.it/books/about/A_Survey_of_Modern_Algebra.html?id=FnP7sHxjt6gC&redir_esc=y) (4th ed - 1977), page 133:

> **Definition**. A group $G$ is a system of elements with a binary operation 
>   which ...

From the '90s, we can see the "new wave" emerging:

- Saunders Mac Lane & Garrett Birkhoff, [Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=L6FENd8GHIUC&printsec=frontcover) (3rd ed 1991), page 43:

> A *group* $G$ is a set $G$ together with a binary operation...,

but see page 85:

> A *ring* $R=(K,+,∙,1)$ is a set $R$ with two binary operations...

and :

- David Dummit & Richard Foote, [Abstract algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=QkAxJgAACAAJ) (3ed - 2004), page 16:

> A *group* is an ordered pair $(G,∙)$ where $G$ is a set ...

Comment: I don't think this is addressing the question that was asked. The OP wants to know who *first* started using just the letter for the underlying set as the label for a group, ring, or field.  The answer is that this has been done since these concepts were first defined.